# How to set a button background and back according to selected state not pressed state

Tags: java, android

I currently have a sound button,and I would like to change its background every time when it's selected and clicked(I'm developing on a pair of android glasses, so when the button is selected it's not pressed, thus two different states).

I have used the xml file to change button background when selected so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/no_music"
        android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/no_music"
        android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/music" />
</selector>
```

And together in the `onClick` method of the button, I set the button background according to the state:

```
public void musicPlay(View view) {
    Button music = (Button) findViewById(R.id.music);
        if(isPlaying) {
            music.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.no_music);
            MusicManager.release()
        }else{
            music.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.music);
            MusicManager.start(this);
        }
    isPlaying = !isPlaying;
}
```

When I click the button, each time it would change its background. But when I select it, it would only change background once. Is there any method that I can use to make selected state the same as the pressed one?

Thank you very much.

Comment: could you add the code as code and post your xml? did you use a selector drawable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this in your code:

```
public void musicPlay(View view) {
    Button music = (Button) findViewById(R.id.music);
        if(isPlaying) {
            music.setPressed(true);
            MusicManager.release()
        }else{
            music.setPressed(false);
            MusicManager.start(this);
        }
    isPlaying = !isPlaying;
}
```

Also in your xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/no_music" android:state_selected="true"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/no_music" android:state_pressed="true"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/music"/>
    </selector>
```

Comment: if my answer helped you, please mark it as correct or upvote it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you could make an drawable resource as resource for the button:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:constantSize="true">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/musicon" android:state_checked="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/musicoff" android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/default" />
```

something like this should work. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Set your button pressed property to `true`, then verify if your button `background.xml` file has selected item.